# Get distinct attributes for XML nodes

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I`ve been trying to get distinct attribute values from the 
XML:
dim i,xmlOx,arr(100)
"xmlOx" has following xml structure

```
  <root>
    <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
    <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
    <a x="Country" y="Bird"/>
    <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
    </root>
```

asp:

```
for i=0  xmlOx.selectNodes("a").length-1
 arr(i)=xmlOx(i).selectNodes("a").getAttribute("x")
next
```

Like,here i`ve to get "x" attribute values but I don`t need duplicates.Then I need to add the values to an array in vbscript.

Please someone tell me how we do it?

Answer (score 0):

The theory is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13512982/603855).

Code:

```
  Dim sXml : sXml = Join(Array( _
      "<root>" _
    , "<a x=""Animal"" y=""Bird""/>" _
    , "<a x=""Animal"" y=""Bird""/>" _
    , "<a x=""Country"" y=""Bird""/>" _
    , "<a x=""Animal"" y=""Bird""/>" _
    , "</root>" _
  ))
  Dim oXDoc : Set oXDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  oXDoc.loadXml sXml
  WScript.Echo oXDoc.xml

  Dim xObjXml  : Set xObjXml  = oXDoc.documentElement.childNodes
  Dim dicAttrs : Set dicAttrs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim i
  For i = 0 To xObjXml.length - 1
      Dim a : a = xObjXml(i).getAttribute("x")
      dicAttrs(a) = dicAttrs(a) + 1
  Next
  Dim aAttrs : aAttrs = dicAttrs.Keys()
  WScript.Echo Join(aAttrs)
```

Output:

```
<root>
        <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
        <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
        <a x="Country" y="Bird"/>
        <a x="Animal" y="Bird"/>
</root>

Animal Country
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Please check my update to the post and reply back please.Use exact variables.

Comment: @user1495475 - sorry I can't do that, because your code fragment is meaningless.

Comment: I can`t put all the code,so i`ve put some random xml,please see if you can help it.

Comment: Main Problem is it`s throwing error at "dicAttrs.Keys()" like "Microsoft VBScript runtime (0x800A01A8)Object required".